# Problem binding variable to DB query with PDO, MVC and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, pdo

In my MVC for a village school library, which I am preparing pro bono, of course, I have a PHP form that has to initialize the search process (findMember.php)

```
<?php 
// findMember.php

require APPROOT . '/views/inc/headerAdmin.php'; 
?>
<h1><?php echo $data['title']; ?></h1>
<h4><?php echo $data['description']; ?></h4>
<div class="row">
<?php //flash('register_success'); ?>
    <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
        <div class="card card-body bg-light mt-5">
            <h2>Karton đaka</h2>
            <form action="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/zaduzenja/findMember" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <label for="ime">Ime: <sup>*</sup></label>
                            <input type="text" name="ime" class="form-control form-control-lg <?php echo (!empty($data['ime_err'])) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $data['ime']; ?>">
                            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $data['ime_err']; ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
<!--                <div class="form-group">-->
<!--                    <div class="row">-->
<!--                        <div class="col">-->
<!--                            <label for="razred">Razred: <sup>*</sup></label>-->
<!--                            <input type="text" name="razred" class="form-control form-control-lg --><?php //echo (!empty($data['razred_err'])) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?><!--" value="--><?php //echo $data['razred']; ?><!--">-->
<!--                            <span class="invalid-feedback">--><?php //echo $data['razred_err']; ?><!--</span>-->
<!--                        </div>-->
<!--                        <div class="col">-->
<!--                            <label for="odelenje">Odelenje: <sup>*</sup></label>-->
<!--                            <input type="text" name="odelenje" class="form-control form-control-lg --><?php //echo (!empty($data['odelenje_err'])) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?><!--" value="--><?php //echo $data['odelenje']; ?><!--">-->
<!--                            <span class="invalid-feedback">--><?php //echo $data['odelenje_err']; ?><!--</span>-->
<!--                        </div>-->
<!--                    </div>-->
                </div>

                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="submit" value="Nađi karton učenika" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php require APPROOT . '/views/inc/footer.php'; ?>
```

######################################################################

This form sends variable data to the PHP class (Zaduzenja.php)

```
<?php
//   Zaduzenja.php

class Zaduzenja extends Controller {

    private $zaduzenjaModel;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->zaduzenjaModel = $this->model('Zaduzenje');
    }

    public function findMember(){
        // Check for POST
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
            // Process form

            // Sanitize POST data
            $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

            // Init data
            $data = [
                'ime' => trim($_POST['ime']),
//                'razred' => trim($_POST['razred']),
//                'odelenje' => trim($_POST['odelenje']),

                'ime_err' => '',
//                'razred_err' => '',
//                'odelenje_err' => ''
            ];

            // Validate Podatke
            if(empty($data['ime'])){
                $data['ime_err'] = 'Unesite ime učenika';
            }

//            if(empty($data['razred'])){
//                $data['razred_err'] = 'Unesite razred učenika';
//            }
//
//            if(empty($data['odelenje'])){
//                $data['odelenje_err'] = 'Unestite odelenje učenika';
//            }

            // Make sure errors are empty
            if(empty($data['ime_err'])){
                // Validated
//                print_r($data);

                // Pretraži bazu učenika
                if($this->zaduzenjaModel->findMemberCard($data['ime'])){
      //                    die($data);
//                    flash('register_success', 'Uspešan unos knjige u bazu');
                        redirect('zaduzenja/searchResult');
                    } else {
                        die('Something went wrong');
                    }

            } else {
                // Load view with errors
                $this->view('zaduzenja/findMember', $data);
            }

        } else {
            // Init data
            $data = [
                'ime' => '',
//                'razred' => '',
//                'odelenje' => '',

                'ime_err' => '',
//                'razred_err' => '',
//                'odelenje_err' => ''
            ];

            // Load view
            $this->view('zaduzenja/findMember', $data);
        }

    }

    public function searchResult(){
        $clanovi = $this->zaduzenjaModel->findMemberCard($data);
        $data = [
            'title' => 'Spisak članova biblioteke',
            'description' => '',

            'clanovi' => $clanovi
        ];

        $this->view('zaduzenja/searchResult', $data);
    }

}
```

########################################################################################

After all necessary checks, data are sent to the new PHP class (Zaduzenje.php) which has to process DB query and send the result to file searchResult.php

```
<?php
// Zaduzenje.php

class Zaduzenje {
    private $db;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new Database;
    }

    // Nadji člana za zaduženje
    public function findMemberCard($ime){
//        die($ime);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM biblio_clanovi WHERE ime = :ime";
        $this->db->query($sql);
        // Bind value
        $this->db->bind(':ime', $ime);
//        $this->db->bind(':razred', $razred);
//        $this->db->bind(':odelenje', $odelenje);

        $results = $this->db->resultSet();
        return $results;
    }
}
```

###################################################################

PROBLEN:

For some reason, I can't bind the variable $ime. It confuses me that

```
$this->db->bind(':ime', $ime);
```

does not pass variable to Query although it is send function. I checked it with die($ime) function.
When I write

```
$this->db->bind(':ime',  'Stefan');
```

everything work just fine.

Database.php

```
<?php
/*
 * PDO Databace Class
 * Connect to database
 * Create prepared statements
 * Bind values
 * Return rows and results
 */
class Database{
    private $host = DB_HOST;
    private $user = DB_USER;
    private $pass = DB_PASS;
    private $dbname = DB_NAME;
    private $charset = DB_CHARSET;

    private $dbh;
    public $stmt;
    private $error;

public function __construct()
{
    // Set DNS
    $dns = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname . ';charset' . $this->charset;
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION

//        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
//        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
//        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    );

    // Create PDO instance
    try {
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dns, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        echo $this->error;
    }
}

// Prepare statement with query
public function query($sql){
    $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
}

// Bind values
public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
    if(is_null($type)){
        switch(true){
            case is_int($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                break;
            case is_bool($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                break;
            case is_null($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                break;
            default:
                $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
        }
    }
    $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
 }

// Execute the prepared statement
public function execute(){
    return $this->stmt->execute();
}

// Get result set as array of objects
public function resultSet(){
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

// Get single record as object
public function single(){
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

// Get row count
public function rowCount(){
    return $this->stmt->rowCount();
}

// Poslednji uneti ID
public function lastId(){
    return $this->stmt->lastInsertId();
}
}
```

Comment: Please show us your Database class for the methods you're using. We have no clue what goes on in there. Tbh, I don't see any reason to wrap PDO inside a class at all if it's just going to simulate PDO anyway. It only creates unnecessary complexity for no real gain. Just create the PDO instance once and pass it to the classes that needs it instead.

Comment: I just added Database class (Database.php) to my post.